# Return nodes with distinct values based on 2 parameters in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xslt-2.0

In XSLT 2.0 I would like to get the unique nodes with 2 parameters..

For example I have:

```
    <items>
        <item x="1" y="1" z="a"/>
        <item x="1" y="2" z="b"/>
        <item x="2" y="1" z="c"/>
        <item x="1" y="2" z="d"/>
        <item x="2" y="2" z="e"/>
    </items>
```

I would like the result to be:

```
    <items>
        <item x="1" y="1"/>
        <item x="1" y="2"/>
        <item x="2" y="1"/>
        <item x="2" y="2"/>
    </items>
```

Is there an easier way to get this?
My current code is really redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/items">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="item" group-by="concat(@x,'#',@y)">
                <item x="{@x}" y="{@y}"/>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Edit:** The context is the first item of the group, so no need for `current-group()[1]`. Thanks Michael Kay.

Comment: Since the context item within for-each-group is current-group()[1], you could remove the variable and just use `<item x="{@x}" y="{@y}"/>. But perhaps the longer form is more readable.